# TypeScript: implementing pipe function using tuple

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-generics

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgHgJIBooHkB8UC8UAUAlgFxRICUu26A3ALABQjAZgK5wDGwhA9nFGEKQA6oWAALAIIAnaQkloAQpnxgAhtLUBbAM6kA2vARq4INJMxojCqMoC6lAN6MoUDnx08ANhAB0XngBzVQ1tHXJ6BgBfRhZ2Ll5%20QRExKWlAnXklFTVSIxMzKAs0ACM8xBtlJxc3D28-AOC1CMYYpgZ3OB1gKE9WaQ5oPAQsfAATNWBcjHJy41M0LCoCShxsCanIzu6oYE0u5h5pLVwoZEWVZjhSIlIKZfRV7FuyJ6grohb2gHpvqABlVgcQY6HQAQkYvyKUBMY1sUEIcGYEFkEDhah0UDGEB0hGkaKggGQCARCCCiCQyDLyU6OGGkOCsLQlFFQKJKU4MpkozCMZJk1KUnT4Gp9AYQfC06YARlZ5BQNT2Jh0h2O%20Hw%20J0rC8wDeGq1wF8zUYX0hfwAorIjlAALRQAAK0h4kGkoCgAHI1G6sTwcVA4DwehAAB6EHZ8XbgaBu9gAa39AHc4G7TdDYfDQJB0ZjYwn%20ISAAV88lpOSSU45niJ9l4CuJnkMIsC2T4fSiwYSulQGVROW7fbKo5aNV67W6nH6w3kByRFPCaAcExQcQQLxgXbL2paQQ%20aS7HgIpEsstpxQpxQgP0BqCsXFwQJQQIQOAowgcd7xbgeXmk4syaQt-A3g7aVZTQRUDkHYdx1HZYRwNZpp1iBgoXQXdgzALxX2ALwLwzRF7wkaBH2faRXx0b8UgpZt9BFHh%20kGBBJXpRlmV3KIVCYrtQIVfsVSHdVoJ1WDBMneUGEQn4-kUVgeiQN04TAfFkV3eNoDGQgxiTHpxDUAA3aBgB4CF2iAA)

I am implementing a pipe function but with one difference from regular implementations: rather than taking functions as arguments, it must accept an array of functions passed as a single argument.

Like most implementations, my pipe implementation captures the input and output types of each function using type varaibles.

```
// simplified without overloads
type Fn<I, O> = (i: I) => O;

function pipeWithArr<A, B>(params: [Fn<any, A>, Fn<A, B>]) {
  console.log(params);
}
```

For comparison, common implementations like https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/function.ts.html#pipe would look like this:

```
function pipeWithArgs<A, B>(a: Fn<any, A>, b: Fn<A, B>) {
  console.log(a);
}
```

Although both implementations work similarly, the former is less capable at infering the input and output types variables – specifically when those types are inferred by generic functions within the array itself.

```
const source = <O>(data: O): Fn<any, O> => () => data;
const transform = <I, O>(fn: (i: I) => O) => (i: I) => fn(i);

// Success!
// A and B inferred as desired – pipeWithArgs<A = { a: number }, B = number>
pipeWithArgs(
  source({ a: 1 }),
  transform((result) => result.a)
);

// Error - Property 'a' does not exist on type 'unknown'
// A and B typed as unknown – pipeWithTuple<A = unknown, B = unknown>
pipeWithArr([source({ a: 1 }), transform((result) => result.a)]);
```

We can help the compiler to infer A and B:

```
// By not using generic functions
pipeWithArr([() => ({ a: 1 }), transform((result) => result.a)]);

// Or explictly typing the generics
pipeWithArr([
  source<{ a: number }>({ a: 1 }),
  transform((result) => result.a),
]);
```

However, it is desired that the user of `pipeWithArr` can:
a) be able to pass it generic functions
b) not need to provide explicit types

Are there any workarounds to make `pipeWithArr` work like `pipeWithArgs` or is this a limitation of the compiler? Or, a misunderstanding of how it should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears not to be possible currently (v4.6).

[Meta-issue: Use Full Unification for Generic Inference? #30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134) tracks the overarching problem.

[This comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44999#issuecomment-883531098) may shed light on the mechanism TS uses to infer in this scenario.